# Enter() statement with a function from one data array to multiple arrays? (Adding multiple Gradient Paths)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path, gradient

I'm having a bit of a problem wrapping my head around the syntax of the enter function with that references parts of the data.
The end goal for me is to draw numerous gradient paths on a map. And I have been following the code in http://geoexamples.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/d3-map-styling-tutorial-iv-drawing.html (focusing on bl.ocks.org/rveciana/10668944) which pulls the gradient function code from: bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057 .
I have gotten the code working, but I'm trying to extend it to an array of paths.

My question is, I think, focused on the below part of the code:

```
 svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(quad(sample(line(track), 8)))
.enter().append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
  .attr("d", function(d) { return lineJoin(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], trackWidth); });
```

Lets say, I made a new path which can replace quad(sample(line(track), 8)) with `track01`. I.e.

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(track01)
.enter().append("path")
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
.attr("d", function(d) { return lineJoin(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], trackWidth); });
```

runs. Now, I have another path, called `track02` which runs a new path if I replace `track01` above. I am stuck at is making both of them work. I was wondering if there was anyone with a fix to the functions to make the below code work.

```
 svg.selectAll("path")
    .data([track01,track02])
 .enter().append("path")
 .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
 .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
 .attr("d", function(d) { return lineJoin(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], trackWidth); });
```

I'm trying to emulate what was described in groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/hM5DpnxAtVI to add multiple paths.

Comment: What does the variable `track01` contains?

Comment: I made `var track0` = quad(sample(line(track), 8))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is already an array, what you have to do is concat them together like that :

```
var data = track01.concat(track02);
```

I create a Fiddle for the example : https://jsfiddle.net/7k0wqw7v/